# Does the mutual curse between Prophet and Abu amir qualify as Mubahala?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, seerah

Martin lings in his work "the life of prophet" mentions an incident of first hijri. ***This is much before the revelation of Quran verse 3:61 for mubahala***

A "monk" who went by name Abu Amir comes to prophet and makes a claim that hes upon the religion of ibrahim.

Prophet explains to him that the muslims are upon that religion.

Abu Amir disagrees and prays "May Allah make the liar to die an lonely outcast life"

The prophet says "so be it".

Abu Amir dies far away from human habitations.[image]

It appears from the above incident that a  prayer took place and the result is also seen.

Can this incident qualify as mubahala since it covers the all necessary conditions of mubahala like.

1. Establishment of proof.
2. Sufficient effort to explain the position.
3. Proper wording of prayer.